# Are these functions ordered correctly from smallest to largest growth rate?

Tags: algorithms

I've attempted to put a random list of functions into order from smallest to largest growth rate, but I seem to be doubting myself quite a bit. Does this look accurate? If not, please feel free to point out my errors.

$$
128, 2/N, \sqrt N, 23N, N \log_2 N, N^2 \log_2 N, 42N^3, 2^N, 2^{N+1}, 3^N, N!
$$

Thank you!

Comment: It is not specified, although it's in the context of computer science so I would assume real numbers.

Comment: $128$ is mis-placed.

Answer (score 1):

$$2/n,128,\sqrt n,n\log_2n,n^2\log_2n,$$
and the rest is correct. I'm assuming you mean growth as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: How can $\sqrt{N}$ grow more quickly than $N\log N$?

Comment: Sorry. Not quite awake yet. You are right

Comment: I've edited my answer.